# error index was outside the bounds of the array.(C# ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, weka

(I used Visual Studio 2015 to programming. I wrote the code to predict the result and I used .arff file (from WEKA) to get Instance.)

I had problem when I finished input to variables and run program.
Then it occur an error : **"error index was outside the bounds of the array."** When I input the values into integer variables(from text box) since 0-83,No error occur. But if I input values since 84 or more,It occur error!!!

It occur error at :
**"TextBox1.Text=Convert.ToString(model.classifyInstance(insts.lastInstance()));"**

I don't know how to solve it. Please help.

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using weka.core;
using weka.classifiers.functions;
using weka.classifiers.meta;
using weka.classifiers;

namespace pdhd
{
    public partial class Survey : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            int weight = Convert.ToInt32(txtWeight.Text);
            int height = Convert.ToInt32(txtHeight.Text);
            int sex; if (BoxMale.Checked == true && BoxFemale.Checked == false) { sex = 1; }
            else if (BoxMale.Checked == false && BoxFemale.Checked == true) { sex = 2; }
            else { sex = 0; }
            float H = (height / 100) ^ 2;
            int age = Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text);
            float bmi = weight / H;
            int bloodup = Convert.ToInt32(txtBloodUp.Text);
            int blooddown = Convert.ToInt32(txtBloodDown.Text);
            int ppg = Convert.ToInt32(txtBloodSugar.Text);
            char pardiabete; if (BoxParentDiabete.Checked == true) { pardiabete = 'Y'; } else { pardiabete = 'N'; }
            char parhyper; if (BoxParentHP.Checked == true) { parhyper = 'Y'; } else { parhyper = 'N'; }
            char parheart; if (BoxParentHD.Checked == true) { parheart = 'Y'; } else { parheart = 'N'; }
            char brodiabete; if (BoxBroSisDiabete.Checked == true) { brodiabete = 'Y'; } else { brodiabete = 'N'; }
            char brohyper; if (BoxBroSisHP.Checked == true) { brohyper = 'Y'; } else { brohyper = 'N'; }
            char broheart; if (BoxBroSisHD.Checked == true) { broheart = 'Y'; } else { broheart = 'N'; }
            char waterThirst; if (BoxWaterThirst.Checked == true) { waterThirst = 'Y'; } else { waterThirst = 'N'; }
            char eatthin; if (BoxEatWeightLose.Checked == true) { eatthin = 'Y'; } else { eatthin = 'N'; }
            char weightlost; if (BoxFastWeightLose.Checked == true) { weightlost = 'Y'; } else { weightlost = 'N'; }
            char bodyitch; if (BoxBodyItch.Checked == true) { bodyitch = 'Y'; } else { bodyitch = 'N'; }
            char eyeblur; if (BoxEyeBlur.Checked == true) { eyeblur = 'Y'; } else { eyeblur = 'N'; }
            char handlegnerve; if (BoxHandLegNerve.Checked == true) { handlegnerve = 'Y'; } else { handlegnerve = 'N'; }
            char smoke; if (BoxSmoke.Checked == true) { smoke = 'Y'; } else { smoke = 'N'; }
            char drink; if (BoxBoost.Checked == true) { drink = 'Y'; } else { drink = 'N'; }
            int exercise = Convert.ToInt32(txtExcercise.Text);
            char likesalt; if (BoxLikeSalt.Checked == true) { likesalt = 'Y'; } else { likesalt = 'N'; }
            char urine; if (BoxFrequentPiss.Checked == true) { urine = 'Y'; } else { urine = 'N'; }
            CreateModelDB(sex, age, bmi, bloodup, blooddown, ppg, pardiabete, brodiabete, waterThirst, eatthin, weightlost, bodyitch, eyeblur, handlegnerve, smoke, drink, exercise, likesalt, urine);
             }
        public void CreateModelDB(int SEX, int AGE, float BMI, int BLOODUP, int BLOODDOWN, int PPG, char PARDIABETE, char BRODIABETE, char WATER, char EATTHIN, char WEIGHTLOST, char BODYITCH, char EYEBLUR, char HANDLEGNERVE, char SMOKE, char DRINK, int EXERCISE, char LIKESALT, char URINE) {

            try
            {
                weka.core.Instances insts = new weka.core.Instances(new java.io.FileReader("/ReferenceForVS/Net_Project/data/pdhd_diabete.arff"));

                weka.core.DenseInstance record = new weka.core.DenseInstance(20);


                record.setValue(insts.attribute(0), SEX);
                record.setValue(insts.attribute(1), AGE);
                record.setValue(insts.attribute(2), BMI);
                record.setValue(insts.attribute(3), BLOODUP);
                record.setValue(insts.attribute(4), BLOODDOWN);
                record.setValue(insts.attribute(5), PPG);
                record.setValue(insts.attribute(6), PARDIABETE);
                record.setValue(insts.attribute(7), BRODIABETE);
                record.setValue(insts.attribute(8), WATER);
                record.setValue(insts.attribute(9), EATTHIN);
                record.setValue(insts.attribute(10), WEIGHTLOST);
                record.setValue(insts.attribute(11), BODYITCH);
                record.setValue(insts.attribute(12), EYEBLUR);
                record.setValue(insts.attribute(13), HANDLEGNERVE);
                record.setValue(insts.attribute(14), SMOKE);
                record.setValue(insts.attribute(15), DRINK);
                record.setValue(insts.attribute(16), EXERCISE);
                record.setValue(insts.attribute(17), LIKESALT);
                record.setValue(insts.attribute(18), URINE);

                insts.add(record);
                insts.setClassIndex(insts.numAttributes() - 1);

                weka.classifiers.trees.J48 model = new weka.classifiers.trees.J48();

                model.buildClassifier(insts);

                TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(model.classifyInstance(insts.lastInstance()));

            }
            catch(java.lang.Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: How many instances are there in `pdhd_diabete.arff`?

Comment: There are 20 instances in .arff file. 1st-19th are factors and 20th is result or target class.